# Access 2013 - DlookUp

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I now have tried `DLookUp`, but I do not get the result I want.

My Situation:  I am creating a database for a cinema. It includes tables named cinemas, movies, sold seats, price.

I have made a form where I can record a new "guest". I can select the ID of the Show and then I see the date and the time. I now have recorded some guests and now there should be less seats free. I want to show that on the same form as the one where I record new guests. I don't get up with the `Dlookup`.

I have made this query which calculates how many seats are left but I cannot put that into the form.

```sql
SELECT
    tbl_Vorstellung.ID_Vorstellung,
    tbl_Kino.Kino,
    Sum([tbl_Kino]![Sitzplätze]-[qry(02)PlätzeVerkauft]![AnzahlvonTicketNummer]) AS Ausdr1
FROM
    tbl_Kino
    INNER JOIN ([qry(02)PlätzeVerkauft]
    INNER JOIN tbl_Vorstellung
    ON [qry(02)PlätzeVerkauft].ID_Vorstellung = tbl_Vorstellung.ID_Vorstellung)
    ON tbl_Kino.ID_KINO = tbl_Vorstellung.FS_KINO
GROUP BY
    tbl_Vorstellung.ID_Vorstellung,
    tbl_Kino.Kino;
```

Comment: SELECT tbl_Vorstellung.ID_Vorstellung, tbl_Kino.Kino, Sum([tbl_Kino]![Sitzplätze]-[qry(02)PlätzeVerkauft]![AnzahlvonTicketNummer]) AS Ausdr1
FROM tbl_Kino INNER JOIN ([qry(02)PlätzeVerkauft] INNER JOIN tbl_Vorstellung ON [qry(02)PlätzeVerkauft].ID_Vorstellung = tbl_Vorstellung.ID_Vorstellung) ON tbl_Kino.ID_KINO = tbl_Vorstellung.FS_KINO
GROUP BY tbl_Vorstellung.ID_Vorstellung, tbl_Kino.Kino;

Comment: thank you. May i tell it to you otherwise. I the Quere works nice. It counts every sold seat. My final Question is : How i do show the "left Seats" in a form? I Work wiwth Dlookup.

I createt a new text field. There i want to see how many seats for which show are available. i Want to take the ID which i select on the top, to work with the quere. the quere should take the selected ID of the top.

Comment: See if I understood correctly.  I will call the query in your question "qryUnsoldSeats".  So then your form has 27 as its current `ID` value.  You can then get the number of unsold seats by looking up ID=27 in qryUnsoldSeats.  So perhaps: `SELECT Ausdr1 FROM qryUnsoldSeats WHERE ID_Vorstellung = 27;`  If that `SELECT` statement returns what you need, we can transform it into a `DLookup` expression.

Comment: Well. It worked now! thank you! Now i have a "design" error. When i didnt select a value yet, there is the field #error#. when i select a value it disappears and shows me the right information. How can i put there a "If theres Nothing, Write "Bitte auswählen"

Comment: I am very lost here, but it sounds like you're making progress in spite of my confusion.  And you have your `Dlookup()` mostly working now, except when ID is Null.  So perhaps you can use that `DLookup` in an `IIf()` expression ... `IIf(IsNull(ID),  "Bitte auswählen", DLookup(...))`

Answer (score 0):

Save your working query as a new name, for this example `MyQuery`

Then use

```
DLOOKUP("Ausdr1", "MyQuery", "ID_Vorstellung=SomeValue AND Kino=SomeValue")
```

On your form.  You'll have to put in the SomeValue values based on fields on your form, etc.